# Python: Allow users to sign in and tweet

Tags: python, twitter

Although there is many different available resources out there, this isn't really an explained guide or examples showing what I need for my program. I am looking to be able to allow the user to enter their username and password or some kind of similar authentication and maybe store it in a .txt file somewhere. This would then will be loaded for logging in so that the user will be able to enter for example "tweet hello there" resulting in the person tweeting 'hello there'.

Comment: Honestly, it's really not a good idea to put yourself in charge of managing other people's credentials to third party systems unless you're really resourced to do it correctly. Far better to provide access through some kind of OAuth login. Python-social-auth is a great library for this. https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth

Comment: The file holding their login details would be stored on the device that they are using.

Comment: Honestly, that's probably worse. There are reasonably secure methods for reliably brokering access to third party systems. Use them. This truly isn't something you want to do casually.